# Light not affecting volumetric cube, but only in specific project file?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I have a project where I am trying to shine a light through a volumetric cube. Everything was working as expected until I unknowingly changed some setting which made it start behaving differently.

Both projects are using Cycles, and the light / object settings are the same for both projects.

Here's how it behaves in the project I was working in:
[image: Light not affecting volumetric cube]

But when I place the light *inside* of the volume cube I get this:
[image: light inside of cube]

I create a new project and it works as expected:
[image: new project]

My node setup for the volumetric cube is the same across both projects:
[image: node setup volumetric cube]

Interestingly, increasing the light radius gives different results for each project. This is what it looks like in my broken project vs. a new project with default settings:
[image: Light Radius]

The cube object properties are the same across both projects:
[image: cube object properties]

Light settings are the same across both projects:
[image: light settings]

[image: light settings]

I'll attach both project files in a comment below.

Does anyone know what this could be? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Working / New Project:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Zw5LN55Z" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Zw5LN55Z/)

Broken Project:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NmgDo68r" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NmgDo68r/)

Answer (score 1):

Light Paths > Transparent under Render properties was set to 0 in my "broken" project, changing that made everything work as expected.